# What is the best way to provide blocs using flutter_bloc package

Tags: android, flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm using `flutter_bloc` package to create an app to fetch data from API, my blocs are so many and I'm providing them to the whole app from the very beginning before even creating the material app like this:

```
return MultiBlocProvider(
     providers:BlocProviders().providers(),
     child: MaterialApp(
     theme: mainThemeLight(),
     home: new MainSlider(),
);
```

My providers got so many (about 20) and I think that not all of them should be provided to the whole app

**So what is the best way to provide blocs to the app with best performance expiernce?**

Comment: It's always better to provide your bloc only to the Widgets that need it, otherwise you will be using resources unnecessarily. Read this for details https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutterblocaccess

Comment: @FederickJonathan so if I provide the bloc before every `BlocBuilder()` wouldn't it somehow affect the loading time?

Comment: What kind of loading time? And to be clear it's not before BlocBuilder() but before Route

Comment: i m using it in named rout section in main providing it there but it is my question too cuz sometimes when i need a bloc inside of other bloc i have problem i cant provide the bloc to other bloc could somebody please help